# How to call REST endpoint running in EC2 from a Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a NodeJS server running on an EC2 instance, orchestrated by Elastic Beanstalk.

I would like to create a Lambda function that is triggered upon certain events in AWS Cognito. I want the Lambda function to make a POST call to my NodeJS server.

How can this be done?

Comment: Is the NodeJS server reachable publicly over the internet?

Comment: Yes it is, but the endpoint that I want the lambda to call should only be called by the lambda

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, EC2 and Lambda are not integrated out of the box. You'll need to expose your EC2 endpoint through a web-server (e.g. Apache) to receive HTTP requests. Then you send a GET or POST request from Lambda to the EC2 server.

You could have both running in a VPC, so that the IP address you use to make requests to your EC2 web-server is only reachable from within your VPC. It won't make your EC2 callable only by the Lambda function but will prevent the external world from calling your EC2 server.

This tutorial might be useful to you: [Configuring a Lambda Function to Access Resources in an Amazon VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html).

Comment: Does this work if I'm using Elastic Beanstalk to launch the EC2s?

Comment: It should, you can configure EBS to run inside the same VPC as your Lambda function: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.vpc.html

Comment: I am trying to something similar. Could it be possible to get the EC2 resource/ips to call from lamda without hardcoding it? My concern is would set up work if we start-stop or terminate the ec2 instance?

Comment: Before calling the EC2 HTTP endpoint, use the [`DescribeInstances` API endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstances.html) to get the instance public ip-address and then make the Lambda HTTP request. You can use one of the [AWS SDKs](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tools-sdks/) for calling the `DescribeInstances` API. Lambda will obviously need permissions to perform the `DescribeInstances` action.